# R's data.table - How to find an integer value and mutiply the values of the subsequent columns together?

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say one has the following data.table defined in R

```
Drug1   Dose1   Freq1   Drug2   Dose2   Freq2   Drug3   Dose3   Freq3
1234567890  2   1   1548768954  23  2   2222132435  2   2
4356678344  2   2   6547894356  3   1   2123456789  2   2
5673452976  4   1   1234567890  4   0.5 4568789076  33  4
```

How would one search for a particular integer value only in columns "Drug1"-"Drug[x]" and, if found, create a new variable that is the product of the values of the two following columns, corresponding to the same row where the integer value was found (all other values in this new variable should be NA)?

Note: the integer values in "Drug[x]" columns are all of length 10 (e.g. 1234567890, 4593480033, etc.) and the search term of interest is only of length 5, starting with the first 5 digits of the integer (e.g. 12345, 45934, etc).

So if my search term is integer value 12345, the result would look something like this:

```
Drug1   Dose1   Freq1   Newvar1 Drug2   Dose2   Freq2   Newvar2 Drug3   Dose3   Freq3
1234567890  2   1   2   1548768954  23  2   NA  2222132435  2   2
4356678344  2   2   NA  6547894356  3   1   NA  2123456789  2   2
5673452976  4   1   NA  1234567890  4   0.5 -2  4568789076  33  4
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try something like: `dt[,list(NewVar1=Dose1*Freq1*(NA^!grepl("^12345",Drug1)))]`, assuming `dt` is your `data.table`.

Comment: akrun, yes, it should be +2. It's a typo.

Comment: Thanks Nicola, that's the sort of thing I'm after. Now to try it out!

Comment: Nicola, how would you dynamically change the last digit in the variable names "Dose" and "Freq" so they cover the range 1-50. In other words, I have to search through about 50 columns of "Drug" [Drug1-Drug50] for a certain number, then, when found, multiply the "Dose" and "Freq" columns with the same corresponding last digit only.

Comment: Preferably without using a loop. The only numbers that need to be incremented are the single digits after "Dose", "Freq", "NewVar" and "Drug". Thanks.

Comment: If possible, it's probably easiest to "flatten" your data structure. E.g. only use the following column names: RowID, Drug, Dose, Freq. Then you only have to search a single column.

Comment: Thanks Dirk however Nicola's suggestion appears closest to the one I'm searching for.

Answer (score 3):

You could try `Map`

```
v1 <- grep("Drug", colnames(df))
m1 <- matrix(sort(v1+rep(1:2,each=3)),ncol=3)
df[paste0('NewVar',1:3)] <- Map(function(x,y) {
      x1 <-substr(df[,x],1,5)==12345
     Reduce(`*`,df[y]*(NA^!x1))}, v1, split(m1, col(m1)))
df
#       Drug1 Dose1 Freq1      Drug2 Dose2 Freq2      Drug3 Dose3 Freq3 NewVar1
#1 1234567890     2     1 1548768954    23   2.0 2222132435     2     2       2
#2 4356678344     2     2 6547894356     3   1.0 2123456789     2     2      NA
#3 5673452976     4     1 1234567890     4   0.5 4568789076    33     4      NA
#  NewVar2 NewVar3
#1      NA      NA
#2      NA      NA
#3       2      NA
```

#### Update

May be you can try a `for` loop with `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 DT <- as.data.table(df)
 nm1 <- grep('Drug', colnames(DT))
 nm2 <- lapply(nm1, function(x) c(x+1,x+2))
 nm3 <- paste0('NewVar', seq_along(nm1))

 for(j in seq_along(nm1)){
     DT[, (nm3[j]):= Reduce(`*`,DT[,nm2[[j]],with=FALSE
         ]*NA^!substr(DT[[nm1[j]]],1,5)==12345)]
  }

 DT
 #        Drug1 Dose1 Freq1      Drug2 Dose2 Freq2      Drug3 Dose3 Freq3 NewVar1
 #1: 1234567890     2     1 1548768954    23   2.0 2222132435     2     2       2
 #2: 4356678344     2     2 6547894356     3   1.0 2123456789     2     2      NA
 #3: 5673452976     4     1 1234567890     4   0.5 4568789076    33     4      NA
  #   NewVar2 NewVar3
  #1:      NA      NA
  #2:      NA      NA
  #3:       2      NA
```

Or a slightly changed alternative based on the `index` numbers using @nicola's approach

```
 DT <- as.data.table(df)
 indx <- 1:3
  for(j in indx){
    DT[, (paste0('NewVar', j)):=  DT[[paste0("Dose",j)]]*
    DT[[paste0("Freq",j)]]*(NA^!substr(DT[[paste0("Drug",j)]],1,5)==12345)]
   }
 DT
 #        Drug1 Dose1 Freq1      Drug2 Dose2 Freq2      Drug3 Dose3 Freq3 NewVar1
 #1: 1234567890     2     1 1548768954    23   2.0 2222132435     2     2       2
 #2: 4356678344     2     2 6547894356     3   1.0 2123456789     2     2      NA
 #3: 5673452976     4     1 1234567890     4   0.5 4568789076    33     4      NA
 #   NewVar2 NewVar3
 #1:      NA      NA
 #2:      NA      NA
 #3:       2      NA
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Drug1 = c(1234567890, 4356678344, 5673452976), 
Dose1 = c(2L, 2L, 4L), Freq1 = c(1L, 2L, 1L), Drug2 = c(1548768954, 
6547894356, 1234567890), Dose2 = c(23L, 3L, 4L), Freq2 = c(2, 
1, 0.5), Drug3 = c(2222132435, 2123456789, 4568789076), Dose3 = c(2L, 
2L, 33L), Freq3 = c(2L, 2L, 4L)), .Names = c("Drug1", "Dose1", 
"Freq1", "Drug2", "Dose2", "Freq2", "Drug3", "Dose3", "Freq3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really just have 3 drugs, you can just manually repeat the creation of `Newvar` three times and then rearrange the columns:

```
drug.id <- 12345
df[, 'Newvar1'] <- ifelse(abs(df[, 'Drug1'] - drug.id*100000)<100000, 
                          df[, 'Dose1'] * df[, 'Freq1'], 
                          NA)
```

However, if this was just an example and your real data has more drugs, it will be easier to reshape the data to long format first and then do your calculations there. If you must, you can always go back to wide format.

```
# read data
df <- read.table(text='Drug1   Dose1   Freq1   Drug2   Dose2   Freq2   Drug3   Dose3   Freq3
1234567890  2   1   1548768954  23  2   2222132435  2   2
4356678344  2   2   6547894356  3   1   2123456789  2   2
5673452976  4   1   1234567890  4   0.5 4568789076  33  4', header=TRUE)
# reshape to long format
long.df <- reshape(df, 
                   direction = 'long', 
                   varying = list(paste0('Drug', 1:3), 
                                  paste0('Dose', 1:3), 
                                  paste0('Freq', 1:3)), 
                   v.names = c('Drug', 'Dose', 'Freq'),
                   sep = '')
# calculation of Newvar
drug.id <- 12345
long.df[, 'Newvar'] <- ifelse(abs(long.df[, 'Drug'] - drug.id*100000)<100000, 
                              long.df[, 'Dose'] * long.df[, 'Freq'], 
                              NA)
# back to wide format
wide.df <- reshape(long.df, 
                   direction = 'wide', 
                   timevar = 'time', 
                   idvar = 'id', 
                   sep = '')
wide.df
```

Comment: I've got more than 50 Drugs, so my preference is to limit typing. Thanks for the idea. I remain curious whether there's a solution that takes advantage of data.table's efficiencies?